# kable caption as tbl-cap in quarto

Tags: quarto, kableextra

In Quarto, table captions for an r-chunk are specified using tbl-cap:. Is it possible to use the caption as provided in a kable function?

````
```{r}
#| label: tbl-cars
#| tbl-colwidths: [60,40]
#| echo: false

library(kableExtra)

kable(head(cars), caption = 'Cars')
```
````

This leads to the output (in html and pdf):

[image]

I also tried with result: asis, but it doesn't work.

(I know that in Quarto, table captions are typically generated using tbl-caption:. However, I am creating a variety of tables using functions that I want to use elsewhere to generate shiny tables, and I also need to pass the caption there.)

Comment: I think it does not work if you want to use quarto's cross-reference. You can turn of quarto's crossreference by using `crossreference: false` in your main YAML, but I assume that this is not your intention.

Comment: It seems to work just fine with the last realises: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/releases

Answer (score 1):

[Wrong:] Works fine in newer (pre)releases.

Update: I think, I was to optimistic ...

In HTML format, it works well and as desired from version v1.4.480 onwards.

In the pdf/LaTeX format, a new issue has emerged where kableExtra adds a label to the table with the prefix tab: cars. This conflicts with Quarto, resulting in two caption labels and two captions in this case:

````
---
title: "Kable Caption Test"
format:
  html: 
    toc: false
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
---

# Test

Lorem @tbl-cars works in html. 

With format pdf kableExtra adds another caption label with the prefix tab: You can reference to this with Table \ref{tab:tbl-cars} (with Errors in html). 

```{r}
#| label: tbl-cars
#| echo: false

library(kableExtra)

kable(head(cars), caption = "Cars")

```
````

In the rendered LaTeX, it looks like this (starting from \begin{document}):

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Test}\label{test}

Lorem Table~\ref{tbl-cars} works in html.

With format pdf kableExtra adds another caption label with the prefix
tab: You can reference to this with Table \ref{tab:tbl-cars}  
(with Errors in html).

\begin{table}

\caption{\label{tbl-cars}}

\centering{

\captionsetup{labelsep=none}

\caption{\label{tab:tbl-cars}Cars}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r|r}
\hline
speed & dist\\
\hline
4 & 2\\
\hline
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

}

\end{table}%



\end{document}
```

Comment: please give exact version number.